# Android Notification Custom View

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-custom-view, remoteview

I need to show a [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) inside a notification, but it always crashes saying

```
Bad notification posted :Couldn't expand RemoteViews
```

I use `remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.icon, bitmap);`

Here's the layout I use

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
    android:id="@+id/icon_group"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_icon"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Edit** : If I replace CircleImageView with a regular ImageView, it works

Answer (score 2):

RemoteViews are not expanded in the context of your app so it doesn't have access to your custom view: `CircleImageView`.

For RemoteViews, you only have access to vanilla UI controls and a subset at that.